# Android, get InputStream to consider redirection

Tags: java, android

I'm using this class to upload a user picture from social networks:

```
class RetrieveImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                URL bitMapURL = new URL(url[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) bitMapURL.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap img) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            // Do something here with the stream
        }
```

This is the url to retrive facebook profile picture:

```
new RetrieveImageTask().execute("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userFacebookId + "/picture?type=large");
```

For some reason the upload fails, now, I `Log` the url and droped it into chrome and there is a redirection to another url that contains the image, so maybe instead of `BitmapFactory` decodes the stream for the actual image it decodes for the redirection.

I don't know if I'm right and what I need is to handle is this redirection, no exception is thrown and I have no clue about things I can examine(such as the stream) except my redirection theory.

**Edit:**

After taken a look at this [website](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/) I edited the code, when looking at the status code(`connection.getResponseCode()`) I get `200` for this url:https://graph.facebook.com/123164414764748/picture?type=large, when using chrome network inspector:

```
Request URL:https://graph.facebook.com/123164414764748/picture?type=large
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 
Remote Address:31.13.90.2:443
```

**BUT:** when initially using `http` and not `https` `connection.getResponseCode()` return `302`.

While all those facts are nice, when taking the full(after redirected) url and hard-coding it just to check if the redirection might not be the problem it looks like it's not, for a reason I have not figure out, yet, the image won't load.

**Solved:**
It was a filename problem, I'm using `Parse-server` and used users emails as filenames, facebook allow you to register with phone so null or something similar got back as the filename and it fail to upload the file.

Comment: Have you tried to execute `followRedirect(true)` on the connection?

Comment: @Robert There is no `followRedirect` method within `HttpURLConnection`, where should I call it?

Comment: what about [`setFollowRedirects()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean))?

Comment: @Robert thanks, it was `setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)`

Comment: @Robert just wanted to let you know that using `setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` is not the same as using the code in the link within my edit, `setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` didn't worked while the code did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpURLConnection` doesn't handle redirection. You need to do it manually.
It means to check for `30x` status codes, read redirection url and to do the second request.

Comment: Please checkout my edit, I did and it looks like it's not the redirection.

Comment: It most certainly does, and it does so by default.

Comment: Thank you alex, when using `http` I do need to handle redirection, I used the link in my answer edit.